# Best way to interact with application logs output from log4j (while also are being updated by application)

Tags: java, multithreading, file, file-io, log4j

May be it is simpler than I think but I am confused on the following:

I want to be able to present to a user (in a graphical interface) the logs produced by Log4j.

I could just read the files as it is and present it, but I was wondering if there is a standard way to do it to so as to also get any updates that happen at the same time from the other parts of the application that log concurrently.

The log4j files could be multiple i.e. rolling appender

Also the presentation could be while there is no logging happening.
I.e. view of logs up to date

**UPDATE:**
I am constraint to Java 6

Comment: Other than log level what other changes in log4j.properties can be important for you?

Comment: The number of files and the size to roll out and that I append.I don't think the conversion pattern is that significant

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 7's NIO2 libraries to get notified when one of multiple files get's modified in a directory, and reread & display it:

http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes

Comment: I am constrained to Java 6. But +1

Comment: In that case I'm afraid the only thing to do is manually do a periodic poll on the files, see if they've changed and rediplay them...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following tools :

[Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html)

[Xpolog](http://www.xpolog.com/)

Comment: I only have to present parts of the logs to the user. This functionality will be part of an application.I am not supposed to use a third party application that displays the data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a database appender (JDBCAppender) and present the log entries from that?

Comment: I can't introduce a database just for this purpose

Comment: fair enough, but if you had already got one, then it would have been a solution to examine I guess? And if you don't care about log entries from previous runs then you could use an in-memory db.

Comment: Since the logger supports appenders, I don't see why an appender should not signal out the logs 'directly' to a GUI form list/memo.  The 'short manual' specifically mentions a 'GUI components' appender.

Answer (score 0):

Fro the [official documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6) of log4j:

**Is there a way to get log4j to automatically reload a configuration file if it changes?**

```
Yes. Both the DOMConfigurator and the PropertyConfigurator support automatic reloading
through the configureAndWatch method. See the API documentation for more details.
```

- [PropertyConfigurator#configureAndWatch](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch%28java.lang.String%29)
- [DOMConfigurator#configureAndWatch](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch%28java.lang.String%29)

For the on-demand reload of log4j config using GUI I would suggest expose it via a servlet in your J2EE application so that whole file can be edited in a web page (text area may be) and once saved you can overwrite your existing log4j file and reload the log4j config.

Comment: How is the relevant?This is for log4j to reload

Comment: Well if your GUI changes log4 config or you change it yourself in filesystem then you'll eventually need to reload the configuration file in order to make it effective.

Comment: My UI must present the logs of the application using log4j.This is not related to log4.xml configuration file

Comment: Well your title is: `Best way to interact with log4j files while also are being updated` And pretty much all answers are trying to solve this problem i.e. how to get changed log4j file into your app.

Comment: The post says: `I want to be able to present to a user (in a graphical interface) the logs produced by Log4j`.I could change the title if it helps

Comment: Yes it is better to change the title so that you will get better responses unlike this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could think about more "OS-level" solution. 
I don't know if you are using win or linux, but on linux there is this realy nice command "tail".
So you could use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create OS process which goes something like "tail -f  yourLogFile.txt".
And then read the OutputStream of the returned [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). Reading the stream will block waiting for new output from the process to be available, and will immediately unblock when such is available, giving you immediate feedback and possibility to read the latest changes of the log file.

However, you might have problems shutting this process down from Java.
You should be able to send SIGTERM signal to it if you know the process id. Or you could start a different process which could lookup the id of the "tail" process and kill it via "kill" command or something similar.

Also I am not sure if there is similar tool available on windows, if this is your platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your own simple appender and have your application include that appender in your log4j configuration, your appender will be called whenever events are written to other appenders, and you can choose to display the event messages, timestamps, etc. in a UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try XpoLog log4j/log4net connector. It parses the data automaticly and has predefined set of dashboards for it:

Follow the below steps

1. Download and install XpoLog from [**here**](https://xpolog.com/)
2. Add the log4j data using the log4j data connector from [**here**](http://wiki.xpolog.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6094975) and
3. deploy the log4j app [**here**](http://wiki.xpolog.com/display/XPOL/Adding+an+Out+of+The+Box+App)